# Zeos Query congelando o programa

Tags: mysql, delphi

Tenho um sistema que faz conexão remota a um servidor com `MySQL` na Web usando Zeos, em alguns casos, onde a conexão costuma oscilar, na hora de executar o Open em uma consulta, o sistema congela, não exibe erro e não trava, a parte visual do sistema continua respondendo normalmente, só que os recursos não executam nenhuma ação, o sistema só volta a funcionar depois de reiniciado. Alguém já teve esse problema, ou já viu algo parecido?

Comment: Sim, use um tratamento de exception para erros de conexão ou uma condicional para loopar quando o retorno da sua query for null e ficar tentando executar a mesma query, isso vai sanar seus problemas, funcionou aqui onde trabalho

Comment: Eu tenho todo o código do sistema dentro de try..except pra evitar que aconteçam travamentos durante a execução das rotinas, visto que alguns clientes têm muitas oscilações na conexão, em caso de erro o sistema deveria cancelar o processo sendo executado, gravar o erro em um log e seguir pra próxima rotina, na maioria funciona normalmente, só que há alguns dias tivemos que mudar a versão do Zeos porque nosso serviço de hospedagem foi migrado pra outra máquina e com isso atualizaram a versão do MySQL, nessa nova versão em alguns casos o sistema trabalha normalmente por um bom tempo

Comment: Mas chega uma hora que ele fecha o ZQuery, insere o SQL e dá o comando de Open, nessa hora ele não abre a consulta e não dá erro, e o mais estranho é que nem o visual trava, mas em todo caso, vou colocar o processo em uma thread e deixar outra rodando pra acompanhar a execução

Comment: Checar a propriedade ``IsConnected`` da conexão antes de dar um ``Open`` da query pode resolver seu problema. Já tentou? Como está o TimeOut?